# PHP return type not as same as i expect

Tags: php, curl, boolean

I'm using curl for sending data and then in response i'm giving some values. If it satisfies then the response should be `true` and if not then it will return string error message.

My code is as below,

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === true){
        return true;
}else{
        return curl_exec($ch);
}
```

In my response file i wrote this,

```
if($_POST['license']=='123456'){
        echo 'License already in use';
}else{
        echo true;
}
```

I think `echo true` is same and first condition `curl_exec($ch)===true)`  should satisfy. I cannot understand where i am going wrong. Please drive me in right way.

**Edit**

I dump it using var_dump and its showing `string` type insead `boolean` -> `string '' (length=0)`

My curl code is

```
    $site = array('license' => $this->key, 'domain' => $this->domain, 'server' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, EXTENSION_VERIFY_URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $site);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === true){
        return true;
    }else{
        return curl_exec($ch);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't calling `curl_exec()` twice result in two separate executions? I doubt this is desired behavior, but I don't think this is even legal, according to the example usage here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php . In addition, I doubt that the response will be a boolean `true` value; it might be a string equal to or containing `"true"`, but it shouldn't be the same type, so your === will fail.

Comment: did you set `return_transfer`? If so, then curl_exec cannot ever return a boolean true. it'll return whatever string was spit out by the url you're requesting.

Comment: post the rest of your code including curl opts

Comment: yes i know not to use `curl_exec()` twice but if i save it in any variable then it will become easy to manipulate my code. That's why i have to used `curl_exec()` twice

Comment: code is serverside so its no more easy to manipulate the result set as it is calling it twice.

Comment: @Marc B : yes i set it `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Comment: then yes, you'll only ever get a boolean false (failure) or a string (success) from curl_exec, NEVER a boolean true.

Comment: Please check my entire code. I've edited the question

Comment: also worth noting that curl will return the called page output as a string only it isn't content aware. so your called page function instead of `return  true;` would have to be `return 'true';`, you're better off returning json from the webservice page and then using json_decode() toget a true object you can compare against. failing that you'd have to use `curl_exec($ch)==='true'` and call it as a string.

Comment: then what should i do @MarcB so i can build what i want

Comment: `if (curl_exec(...) !== false)`

Comment: I used `if (curl_exec(...) !== false)` this. But even in error it execute success code

Answer (score 0):

Calling `curl_exec()` twice is probably what fails. Instead you should store the return value in a variable (e.g. `$result = curl_exec()`), and use that to test.

Besides that, try `echo`ing something like `t` instead of true and `f:License already in use` instead of the string. That way you always have a string returned, if everything works correctly.

Comment: if i store response like `$result = curl_exec()` then a smart guy can be able to change the value of `$result` and my code can break.

Comment: How do you imagine that happening? If you control the code: only if he manages to spoof your response, which requires some serious hacking. If he controls the code (i.e. it's on his server), then he can just replace `curl_exec()` with `true` and skip the license checking entirely.